# distribute a balance on all rows of a table in plsql loop to get the remaining zero

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have below simple and sample data , i want to distribute a balance on all table rows.

**Example**

`Balance  = 2997` `Balance  = -2997` `Balance  = 997` `Balance  = -997`

**Table Rows**

```
  1021  1021-955 = 66
  1021  1021-1021 = 0
  1021  1021-1021 = 0
```

So from above values `955+1021+1021 = 2997`

i want to Use for loop or any other simple way distribute the balance on all rows. Please see below code how i am trying to do

```
DECLARE
   l_balance       NUMBER := 2997;
   l_running_bal   NUMBER := 0;
   l_bal_flg       VARCHAR2 (1) := 'Y';


   CURSOR c
   IS
          SELECT 1021 installment
            FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c LOOP
      IF l_bal_flg = 'Y' THEN
         l_running_bal := l_balance - i.installment;
         l_bal_flg := 'N';
      ELSE
         l_running_bal := l_running_bal - i.installment;
      END IF;


      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_running_bal);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

**Update**

```
  1021  66
  1021  0
  1021  0
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show a more detailed example of you initial data and what the expected result should look like?

Comment: Balance is just a fixed value in a table. i want to pick the value and apply on anohter table so result should look like Update in question

Comment: Please see the Update code in question

Comment: So you want to use the balance amount from values in an other table. It the remaining balance is greater than the value in the table then the value in the table should be reduced to 0 other wise the remaining of the balance should be subtracted from the value in the table? .

Comment: yup , can you please show in some code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess this would do it

```
set serverout on size 20000
DECLARE
   l_balance       NUMBER := 2997;
   l_sub           NUMBER;

   CURSOR c
   IS
          SELECT 1021 installment
            FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN c LOOP
      l_sub := greatest(least(l_balance, i.installment),-i.installment);
      l_balance := l_balance - l_sub;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i.installment||' '||(i.installment-l_sub));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Please try it :-)

Comment: Yes i have tries its looks perfect

Answer (score 1):

following code snippet should work as per the logic required by you..

```
DECLARE
   l_bal_flg              VARCHAR2 (10) := 'Y';
   l_install_amt          NUMBER := 1362;
   l_calcaulatedbalance   NUMBER := 59024;
   l_curr_bal             NUMBER := 0;
   l_tot_inst_amount             NUMBER := 0;
   l_last_bal_amount             NUMBER := 0;
   l_install_amount2             NUMBER := 0;

   l_last_bal_amount2             NUMBER := 0;
   l_residual_amt         NUMBER := 14125;
   l_installment_cnt      NUMBER := 34;
   l_install_seq          NUMBER := 1;
   l_bal_trans            NUMBER :=0;
   l_bal_trans_cnt            NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
-- amount to be balanced at last before transaction
l_tot_inst_amount := l_calcaulatedbalance-l_residual_amt;
l_last_bal_amount := round(((l_tot_inst_amount/(l_installment_cnt-1)) -  l_install_amt) * (l_installment_cnt-1));

-- to get the transaction from which it has to be balanced
IF l_last_bal_amount <> 0
THEN
   l_last_bal_amount2 :=   ABS(l_last_bal_amount);
   l_install_amount2  :=   l_install_amt;
   l_BAL_TRANS := ceil(l_last_bal_amount2/l_install_amt);
   -- to get the amount to be added on first transaction to be balanced
loop
exit when l_last_bal_amount2 < l_install_amt;
l_last_bal_amount2 := l_last_bal_amount2 - l_install_amt;
end loop;

-- to get the exact transaction count on which first balance to be made
l_bal_trans_cnt :=l_installment_cnt-l_bal_trans;
END IF;

   FOR j IN 1 .. l_installment_cnt LOOP

-- adjustment at the transactions to be balanced
         IF l_bal_trans_cnt = l_install_seq THEN
            l_install_amt := l_install_amount2+(l_last_bal_amount2*(l_last_bal_amount/ABS(l_last_bal_amount)));

        elsif l_install_seq > l_bal_trans_cnt  and l_last_bal_amount >0  then
        l_install_amt := l_install_amount2+l_install_amount2;
         END IF;  



      IF l_residual_amt <> 0 THEN
         IF l_installment_cnt = l_install_seq THEN
            l_install_amt := l_residual_amt;
         END IF;
         -- if balance to be paid is the residual amount then no installment to be paid for the current month 
         IF l_curr_bal = l_residual_amt and l_installment_cnt <> l_install_seq THEN
            l_install_amt := 0;
         END IF;         
      END IF;


      IF l_bal_flg = 'Y' THEN
         l_curr_bal := l_calcaulatedbalance - l_install_amt;
         l_bal_flg := 'N';
      ELSE
         l_curr_bal := l_curr_bal - l_install_amt;
      END IF;

      l_install_seq := l_install_seq + 1;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_install_seq||' '||l_install_amt || '  ' || l_curr_bal);


   END LOOP;
END;


-- output:
for calculated balance 59024
34 1315  14125
35 14125  0

for calculated balance 63024
31 1362  22164
32 2591  19573
33 2724  16849
34 2724  14125
35 14125  0

for calculated balance 55024
31 1362  14164
32 39  14125
33 0  14125
34 0  14125
35 14125  0
```